# i have a problem with reactive forms. it says "addForm" has no initializer

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

i created formGroup with some formControls. i have an error because i haven't initialized. how can i fix it?.

```
export class AddFormComponent implements OnInit {
  addForm: FormGroup;  (here is my problem. when i try to add "?" i have an error in html saying addForm<any> | undefined is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<any>)

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.addForm);
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm = new FormGroup({
      productName: new FormControl(),
      .....
    });

  }
```

Comment: Try addForm! : FormGroup;

Comment: i solved it. just moved everything from ngOnInit to constructor. thanks

Comment: Okay. That will solve this warning, but might not be the correct approach in the long run.

Comment: It's related with the new characteristic Angular 14 [Typed Forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms)

Answer (score 0):

i did it with service and works exactly as i wanted to

first component

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataService.songData = this.song; 
 }
```

second component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.song= this.dataService.songData ; 
 }
```